# find time between single waveforms android FFT

Tags: android, time, fft

I have to find out the times between waveforms. How can I find that? I am using FFT. I searched a lot but not getting sufficient answers.
I have input array,
Ex:

```
float[] array = { 1, 6, 1, 4, 5, 0, 8, 6, 6, 6, 1, 0, 5, 6, 1, 8, 3, 0};  
Using FFT, I am getting Spectrum, real part, and Imaginary part.
Based on this find out, Phases and Magnitude.
    mag[i] = Math.sqrt((real[i] * real[i]) + (imag[i] * imag[i]));
    phase[i] = Math.atan2(imag[i], real[i]);
```

I have to find that how much time(ms) the input constantly display in graph. I have attached sample image.
What about cross correlation? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_correlation). Please clarify me. May be I am going in wrong way.

http://i58.tinypic.com/v3kuwg.png and http://i61.tinypic.com/izx66f.gif

Comment: "find out the times between waveforms" is very unclear. Can you please explain what you need to do?

Comment: The time required to complete one cycle, I want to find that time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the images you provided as reference I will assume that you want to find the Period of the fundamental frequency inherent in the time-domain data array you provided in your code above, where your array of 18-samples is this: 
[ 1, 6, 1, 4, 5, 0, 8, 6, 6, 6, 1, 0, 5, 6, 1, 8, 3, 0 ]

However, you didn't provide the sampling-rate of your time-domain data, so in the following analysis I will assume a sampling rate of 10 KHz. You'll have to adjust the answer to fit your actual sampling-rate (aka sampling-frequency.)

This is your raw time-domain data in graphical form, with the DC offset of the data removed (3.7222). This time-series is the input to the FFT. Note the trailing zeroes added automatically by the FFT so that the input length is a power-of-two (32 total samples in this case):

[image: Time-domain input data for the FFT, Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

The frequency spectrum of the data, obtained from the FFT, is this:

[image: FFT spectrum of time-domain data, Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

The frequency peak of maximum-energy occurs at 3438 Hz, which corresponds to a Period of 1/3438 or 0.291 milliseconds.

However, since your data is non-periodic over the sampling interval, you really should window the data prior to processing it with the FFT. Windowing in this case is needed to minimize spectral leakage errors in the FFT. Here I applied the Blackman-Harris 92-dB window to the data, after removing the DC offset (3.7222) from the raw data:

[image: Time-domain input data for the FFT, Blackman-Harris 92-dB window, Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

This is the frequency spectrum of the data, after applying the Blackman-Harris 92-dB window to the data prior to running the FFT:

[image: FFT spectrum of time-domain data, Blackman-Harris 92-dB window, Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

After windowing, the frequency peak of maximum-energy occurs at 3125 Hz, which corresponds to a Period of 1/3125 or 0.320 milliseconds.

Again, you will need to adjust these results for the actual sampling-frequency used to generate your raw data. For example, if your actual sampling frequency is 44.1 KHz, the first peak above occurs at (44.1/10)*3438 or 15162 Hz, with a corresponding Period of 1/15162 or 0.066 milliseconds.

The FFT, windowing, and graphing were done with the [Sooeet FFT calculator.](https://sooeet.com/math/online-fft-calculator.php)

Comment: Thanks for giving your time. I will check this.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what exactly you're asking here.  You have that original real input signal in the time-domain, then taking the fft you will get a set of complex values (real and imaginary) from which you can also get the magnitude and phase.

Is your question what is the time in ms between each input sample?  This depends solely on the sampling rate.  If it's audio, you're likely recording with 44100 Hz (samples/second) on Android, which would lead to 1/44100 or 0.022 ms between each sample.

However, when you're plotting magnitude or phase, that's in the frequency domain.  For those plots you need a set of frequencies, not time values.  Those frequency values are dependent on  the size of the fft and the sampling rate of the input signal.  For example: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12407/what-is-the-relation-between-fft-length-and-frequency-resolution

Comment: I have to normalize the wave and after normalization find the time(duration) of square waves which is higher. I attached image. please take a look.